# SciTe Editor Download and Install?

Tags: python, scite

I am learning Python and for that i download SciTe Editor but it not gives any exe how should i install or use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:
http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html

A full download (1000K) includes the SciTE executable, any required DLLs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the [Windows Executable version](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/scintilla/wscite223.zip?download)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are after an installer with some desktop integration, check out these...

this guy has been compiling a windows installer of SciTE for years (with minor mods):

http://gisdeveloper.tripod.com/scite.html

there is also this:

http://opensource.ebswift.com/SciTEInstaller/